# java.security.KeyStoreException: failed to extract any certificates or private keys - maybe bad password?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, keystore, private-key

I'm using [Not-yet commons SSL](http://juliusdavies.ca/not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3.9/ssl.html) to develop my own TLS Socket.

But always got No private keys found in keystore on following code

```
private SSLServer sslS=null;
//...
sslS=new SSLServer();
KeyMaterial km=new KeyMaterial(certChain, privateKeyFile, certPassword.toCharArray(), privateKeyPassword.toCharArray());
```

---

The certChain used original JRE's cacert:

- C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/security/cacerts

This give me a java.security.KeyStoreException: No private keys found in keystore!

---

The certChain used my own:

- keytool -certreq -alias 127.0.0.1 -keystore ServerKey.jks -file 127.0.0.1.csr

This give me a java.security.KeyStoreException: failed to extract any certificates or private keys - maybe bad password?

But I can 100% sure that my password is right. My password is a simple "123456", there is no reason I can do wrong on it.

---

The privateKey I generated by:

- keytool -genkey -alias 127.0.0.1 -keyalg RSA -keystore ServerKey.jks -keysize 2048

How can I solve this problem, any suggestion ?

Comment: Err, use the right password? The first message is correct: there are no private keys in the `cacerts` file. The second command will only work if you supply the same password you used in the third command.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I can 100% and 100% and 100% that my password is right...my password is just "123456", there is no way I can wrong with this password. I got no way to continued on this, need any suggestion...

Comment: My "127.0.0.1.csr" was generated from my "ServerKey.jks", so it still no private keys in it ?

Comment: A CSR is not a certificate, and it certianly doesn't contain your private key. It is a document for submission to a certificate signing authority, which has no business whatsoever with your private key. What you need to do instead of step 2 is `keytool -selfcert ...`.